# Apache Response Time Monitoring in Hyperic

Tags: apache, monitoring, response-time, hyperic

I seem to be having a hard time getting the Apache module for Hyperic to compile in Ubuntu 8.10.  Has anyone had any luck getting it to work?  Does anyone have a precompiled version?

I am running Hyperic HQ version 4.1.2 build #1053, Apache 2.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by doing the following:

Symbolically link aclocal and automake old hard coded version to your current version (replace version numbers 1.11 to your own):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/aclocal-1.11 /usr/bin/aclocal-1.6
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/automake-1.11 /usr/bin/automake-1.6
```

Rename a conflicting header file:

```
sudo mv /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h /usr/include/openssl/asn_1.h
```

Run the installer:

```
sudo ./build_apache_snmp.sh -r 2.0 /usr/bin/apxs2
```

Once it is finished make sure you follow the directions located at `./README`

Once you have confirmed that the SNMP service is working (using the `snmpwalk` application that the readme file refers to), reverse the steps above to revert system changes just needed to compile the plugin.